# Cannot resume after suspend anymore

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I see a lot of similar questions, but:

1. they are very old (2012-2014)
2. they said it never worked

Instead, my issue is different.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a PC desktop, here the specifications:

```
$ lshw -short -quiet
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
H/W path        Device      Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         Computer
/0                          bus            Motherboard
/0/0                        memory         16GiB System memory
/0/1                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
/0/100/1.1                  bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
/0/100/1.1/0                display        GK104 [GeForce GTX 670]
/0/100/1.1/0.1              multimedia     GK104 HDMI Audio Controller
/0/100/14                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                   communication  7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1a                   bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
/0/100/1b                   multimedia     7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge         7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/1c/0     wlp3s0      network        AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.1                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
/0/100/1c.1/0   enp4s0      network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d                   bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 storage        7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3                 bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/2                        system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/3                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/4                        system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/5                        generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/6                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                        communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/8                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/a            scsi0       storage        
/0/a/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           500GB WDC WD5000AAVS-0
/0/a/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume         465GiB EXT4 volume
/0/b            scsi1       storage        
/0/b/0.0.0      /dev/sdb    disk           256GB SAMSUNG SSD 830
/0/b/0.0.0/1    /dev/sdb1   volume         238GiB EXT4 volume
/0/c            scsi3       storage        
/0/c/0.0.0      /dev/sdc    disk           256GB SAMSUNG SSD 830
/0/c/0.0.0/1    /dev/sdc1   volume         140GiB EXT4 volume
/0/c/0.0.0/2    /dev/sdc2   volume         98GiB EXT4 volume
/0/d            scsi5       storage        
/0/d/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVDRAM GH22LS50
/0/e            scsi6       storage        
/0/e/0.0.0      /dev/sdd    disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/e/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdd    disk           
/1              ztmjfge2h7  network        Ethernet interface
```

I configured the power button to enter the suspend mode.
It worked for almost one year. I use this feature several times per day.

Since a couple of months, it happens that sometimes when I push again the button to resume from the suspend mode, the PC wakes up (I hear fan noise) but the screens remain black and nothing happens. I can only press the reset button or keep pressed the power button to brutally recover the situation.

In these days, this issue appears more often.

Because it's getting worse day by day, I don't think it could be related to an update or a specific event/settings.

But I don't have enough knowledge to understand what's happening and how to fix.

Comment: Which kernel stack are you using on your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system, is it Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server (*you didn't say, only that it's a desktop PC which can use either*).  One quick fix maybe switching to the GA kernel stack (if you're using HWE); but you're vague with timing (*only mentioning belief you've had issues for a couple months*); as the 5.13 HWE kernel installed weeks ago, the prior 5.11 near 6 months ago which doesn't fit your *couple of months*.  I'd like boot a *live* system using the GA kernel & test it, thus no install is required (using you're on HWE)

Comment: It's Ubuntu LTS Desktop

Comment: @guiverc because `dpkg -l | grep hwe` returns nothing I guess I'm not using HWE (I read it's installed with `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`)

Comment: Your installation media determines the default kernel stack; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop defaults to the HWE kernel stack, so assuming it was a 20.04 desktop install that is the default; you need to use a command to add the GA kernel stack, then another command to remove HWE (both can be installed unless you're using specific close-source video drivers). Flavors have different *default* rules; but it's determined by ISO used to install (I don't know your installation media/ISO).  You'll be using 5.4 on 20.04 if using GA stack so I'd have provided kernel details (`uname -r`)

Comment: I'm using the proprietary (close-source I guess) video driver: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] metapackage from nvidia-driver-470

Comment: `$ uname -r` outputs `5.4.0-100-generic`